# Property of "doesn't-pass-the-laugh-test"

Tags: word-usage, hyphenation

What kind of property does *doesn’t-pass-the-laugh-test* have in the expression

> which escalates unreliability to the **doesn’t-pass-the-laugh-test**
>   level

taken from this [article](http://www.forbes.com/sites/daviddisalvo/2012/05/19/how-one-flawed-study-spawned-a-decade-of-lies/)? Is it an adjective or a noun?

Answer (score 6):

Here's the full context:

> ...he conducted the participant interviews by phone,
>   which escalates unreliability to the **doesn’t-pass-the-laugh-test level**.
>   By phone, researchers aren’t able to evaluate essential
>   non-verbal cues that might cast doubts on verbal responses. Phone
>   interviews, along with written interviews, carry too much guesswork
>   baggage to be valuable in a scientific study, and Spitzer certainly
>   knew that.

It's called a [*compound modifier*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier), and in this example, it functions like an adjective. In particular, it modifies the word *level*.